# android ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() not found

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am trying to make runtime permissions backward compatible with older devices but using the support library i cant find `checkSelfPermission()` static call in `ContextCompat` class, but its documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String))

Here is my project gradle settings:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.myprogram.cool"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 39
    versionName "3.0"
}
```

and here is the dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
```

any idea what i am missing ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have migrated from eclipse adding the below line wont work

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

While migrating, it adds appcompatv4 as an external dependent library.
Make sure you have deleted the appcompatv4 library from the libs folder and then it should start working

Answer (score 40):

`checkSelfPermission()` didn't get introduced into the native `Context` until API 23. So you will need to use at least version 23.0.0 of the support library.

You should change this

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'`

to this

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'`

Comment: I tried this thing but compilation error as  minSdkVersion 16 ! how to solve this ?

Comment: please beware of this behavior when your minSdkVersion < 23 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407250/checkselfpermission-method-is-not-working-in-targetsdkversion-22

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure class `exampleActivity` class is extending from `AppCompatActivity`.
2. Make sure that your minSdkVersion is 23 in the build.gradle file.
3. Sync your gradle after making this change.

That should work.