# On allow permission in AndroidFragment causes application to crash?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions

Hi I am asking camera permission in android from my fragment using following code :

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                    MainActivity.PROFILEIMAGE_REQUEST);
```

Then handling the permission result in same fragment using following code :

```
case MainActivity.PROFILEIMAGE_REQUEST: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                    Log.e("Fragment","In OnRequestPermission onRequestPermissionsResult");
                    dispatchTakePictureIntent(MainActivity.PROFILEIMAGE_REQUEST);                }
                return;
            }
```

Now when I run application for first time it asks the camera permission when as soon as I click on allow my application crashes in background then I see permission box for storage.

Also code in MainActivity :

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
        Log.e("MainActivity", "In OnRequestPermission 1");

        if (fragments != null) {
            for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
                switch (requestCode) { 
.
.
.
 case PROFILEIMAGE_REQUEST:
                        if (fragment instanceof ProfileFragment) {
                            fragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
                            Log.e("MainActivity","In OnRequestPermission PROFILEIMAGE_REQUEST");
                            return;
                        }
                        break;
.
.
.
.
.
}
}
}
```

Unable to get the logs for crash following stack trace is coming when I see the warning filtered logs :

```
W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{b66a7b9 u0 com.bootinfotech.queue.patient/com.indexnine.patient.activity.MainActivity t160}: app died, no saved state
```

Also I am unable to get exact error which causes the application to fail. What might have gone wrong. Device used for testing Moto G4 (Android M).

Also debugger is disconnected as soon as I click on allow for camera permission system dialog box.

Comment: you can ask or check for permission inside your Activity class. And handle its result in activity class too.

Comment: Please, provide more code

Comment: @Vyacheslav I am getting error only for first time run not on second run, same code is able to get image on second run

Comment: @amolanerao , again: please, more code to check this code. your `requestPemissons` looks fine. The other code is initeresing too.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714787/android-m-permissions-onrequestpermissionsresult-not-being-called. Use FragmentCompat.requestPermission

Comment: @Vyacheslav please have look @ edited question, if above code is not enough to describe, please let me know what else from my fragment as well as activity I should paste

Comment: @Raghvendra I have updated my qiestion I am delivering the result to fragment using code in activity please have look

Comment: @amolanerao Are u able to get the call back at onRequestPermissionsResult()? Post your build.gradle file

Comment: @Raghavendra Nope as soon as I click on allow button on System permission dialog application vanishes without any error log.

Comment: @amolanerao Can u tell me the target sdk of your app?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 22, buildToolsVersion "22.0.1", targetSdkVersion 22

Comment: @amolanerao can u change the target sdk to 23 and try once.

Comment: Great !!! Target Sdk was the problem, thank you very much Raghvendra, please post your comment as answer so that I can up-vote.

Comment: @amolanerao glad that helped:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your target sdk is below 23. The permission result will always return 0(PERMISSION_GRANTED). Change the target sdk version to 23 and try.

Ref: [CheckSelfPermission method is not working in targetSdkVersion 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407250/checkselfpermission-method-is-not-working-in-targetsdkversion-22)