# Permission on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions

I have review other questions regarding the permission on android. But I still didnt get the solution for fragment. Why the dialog of permission is not appear ? Also, it dont show any error log. It just not appear.

I dont want to use FragmentCompat since its require **import android.app.Fragment**

This is my minimum sdk ver.
**minSdkVersion 16**

```
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


 public class ComplaintFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private void StartCamera(){
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSIONS_CAMERA);
     }
     else {OpenCamera();}
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_CAMERA:
                OpenCamera();
                break;
        }
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you declare this permission `Manifest.permission.CAMERA` in your `AndroidManiFest.xml` file?

Comment: yes, I do declare that permission

Comment: The int variable `PERMISSIONS_CAMERA` must be lower than 255 and larger than 0, check this.

Comment: hey.. one small check. go to your app settings & check that camera permission which is selected or not

Comment: is your camera intent opening?

Comment: @SendraFalvia In which device u r testing? Can u tell us the os version of the device?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

1) Give camera permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

2) Check the permission is granted or not.

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},1);
                                return;
                            } else {
                                oprnCamere();
                            }
```

3) Handel the result from request permission in onActivityResult() method in your fragment class.

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 0: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //permission accepted.
                    openCamera()
                } else {
                    //permission denied.
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`onRequestPermissionsResult` is deprecated. You should now use [Activity Result](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) to request permission in a fragment.

Her's a simple implementation:

```kotlin
class MyFragment : Fragment {

    private val cameraPermissionResultReceiver = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) {
        if (it) {
            // permission granted
        } else {
            // permission denied
            }
        }
    }

    private fun requestCameraPermission() {
        cameraPermissionResultReceiver.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can try copy 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` to your maniferst

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle(app level) place this code( targetSdkVersion 23)

```
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sampleproject"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
   }
```

Comment: try it once let me know whether it is working or not

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite your function on `onRequestPermissionsResult`. Please try:

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_CAMERA:
                if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    //Camera permission grant
                    OpenCamera();
                else
                    Log.e("error","Oop something wrong with permission");
            break;
     }
```

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34084609/5241603) too. It may be can help answer your question.

Comment: Debug your code to see whether condition is check. Does the permission grant?