# ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission vs Compat.checkSelfPermission

Tags: java, android, runtime-permissions

My app have next settings

- minSdkVersion 8
- targetSdkVersion 23
- compileSdkVersion 23

And I use simple code to get `READ_PHONE_STATE` permissions

```
...
    final List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList(
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);

    if (!permissions.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                permissions.toArray(new String[]{}), 1);

    }
...
```

When I use:

- [ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String))
- [ActivityCompat.requestPermissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int))

Everything works fine.

But when I use:

- [Context.checkSelfPermission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkSelfPermission(java.lang.String))
- [Activity.requestPermissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#requestPermissions(java.lang.String[],%20int))

App just didn't show dialogs.

Anyone have explanation why this happens?

I trying to minimize all dependencies and use `Context` and `Activity` instead `ContextCompat` and `ActivityCompat`

**Update**

Tested on Nexus 9, Android 7.1.1

Comment: what android version are you facing problems in?

Comment: I found answer on my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34084609/902217)