# Android Chartboost SDK Error

Tags: java, android, chartboost

I have the next error with my app with Chartboost sdk integrated:
my app runs fine and show static and video interstitial, I can launch my app several times and always ads show fine but when exit the app and with Android recents button if I close my app then my app crashes on launch (I initialize the Chartboost SDK on Main activity app launch) but if I quit Chartboost sdk then this behaviour does not happen. Does the same thing happen to your apps?
see image bellow, thanks.

Eclipse error log:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ticogames.relaxing.help, PID: 21839
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method       checkSelfPermission(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)I in class     Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat; or its super classes (declaration    of 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat' appears in /data/app   /com.ticogames.relaxing.help-1/base.apk)
at com.moat.analytics.mobile.cha.n.ͺ(SourceFile:5303)
at com.moat.analytics.mobile.cha.n.ʽ(SourceFile:178)
at com.moat.analytics.mobile.cha.n.ˎ(SourceFile:144)
at com.moat.analytics.mobile.cha.n.<init>(SourceFile:81)
at com.moat.analytics.mobile.cha.n.ˏ(SourceFile:63)
at com.moat.analytics.mobile.cha.f.ˎ(SourceFile:108)
at com.moat.analytics.mobile.cha.t$2$2.ˏ(SourceFile:135)
at com.moat.analytics.mobile.cha.t$d$5.run(SourceFile:245)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

[Eclipse Error log - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMPC0.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read the [ask]. You may provide some code or error messages to us, so somebody could help you better.

Comment: post the crash log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32983335/android-contextcompat-checkselfpermission-not-found)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+chartboost+sdk ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error message refers to the support libraries, which would need to be `>=` version `23.0.0`. this issue can be fixed with the module-level `build-gradle` and these dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

and you'd have to implement the below methods, in order to forward the interface methods:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Chartboost.onStart(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Chartboost.onResume(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Chartboost.onPause(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Chartboost.onStop(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Chartboost.onDestroy(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // If an interstitial is on screen, close it.
    if (Chartboost.onBackPressed()) {
        return;
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

[here](https://answers.chartboost.com/en-us/child_article/android) it is basically all explained in detail ...eg. Android API level 27 is not yet being support - therefore API level 26 is the maximum level available (but one can still use those `27.1.1` support libraries).

In every case, the stack-trace and the error description do not match, at all.

Comment: You were right, the problem in Eclipse is how to update that support library now because Google stopped supporting Eclipse for Android development, I exported my apps to Android Studio to easily update the support libraries and everything works very well, thanks !